# Can I upgrade to 64-bit Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Recently, I bought a copy of Windows 8 Pro.

Since I purchased my laptop 3 years ago, I have always run a 32 bit system on it. This includes Vista --> 7 --> 8 Pro

I clearly remember that when I have checked the "System Specs" in Windows 7, it says that my computer is not a 64 bit compatible system. I was like, ok, thats fine.

But today, I suddenly decided to check the specs (with 8 Pro), and suddenly under the System Type, it says: 32-but operating system, x64-based processor:

[image: 1]

I never knew I had a 64-bit processor. Does this mean I am able to "upgrade" Windows 8 to 64-bit (as I have the disk), or is this an error?

Also, if I were to upgrade to 64-bit, would there be a loss of performance, or would Windows run better considering that I would be using the correct "system"?

Comment: Yup, only bother with 64-bit if you have >=4GB RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the Core2Duo T5800 is certainly an x64 processor. You may see a performance boost by upgrading to 64bit, however the biggest advantage is being able to utilize 4GB+ of memory. But, you can't upgrade - you'll have to do a clean install.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I never knew this until I happened to look in the specs today. I only have 2GB - shame :P
Would I be able to do an "upgrade install", or would I have to get all my data back manually after installed x64?

Comment: Nope, cannot upgrade from 32 to 64-bit. A clean install is required. Also, very important - the Win8 Upgrade Assistant will download 32-bit if run on a 32-bit PC, and 64-bit on a 64-bit PC. It cannot cross-download. What you can do is download on a 64-bit PC, then create the ISO and burn to DVD, or create USB, then use that to install on the PC which currently has 32-bit OS on it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just been Googling this: Do you think it is worth doing the upgrade considering I only have 2GB Ram?

Comment: Probably not, if you decided to go to 4GB in the future - I'd do it now rather than later.